# How to select all checkboxes and pass to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I build this code for select all checboxes and pass to controller, I using button when click it check all checkboxes and pick up all variables like `(idtip, idemployee)` trought array send to controller to update database table.

```
            <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>tips</th>
            <th>
                <button id="btnClick" class="btnClick">Select all</button>

            </th>
            </tr>
```

Here is my input and script.

```
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getCheIdTip_Result>)Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.idtip</td>
        <td>@item.tipname</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pure-checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip">
                  <input type="checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip" class="checktip" 
                  checked="@(item.idemployee == ViewBag.idemployee ? true : false)" 
                  name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
                 <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewData["idemployee"]" name="idemployee" id="idemployee" class="idemployee" />
<script>
    $('.pure-checkbox').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('td').toggleClass('chked')
    })

    var wantedids = [idemployee,idtip]

    $("#btnClick").click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $('.pure-checkbox').length; i++) {
            if ($('.pure-checkbox').eq(i).parents('td').hasClass('chked')) {
                wantedids.push(
                    $('.pure-checkbox').eq(i).attr('idtip')
                )
            }
        }
        $.post("UrlSettingsDocument.Tips", { ids: wantedids },

        )
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I using button when click it check all checkboxes and pick up all
> variables like (idtip, idemployee) trought array send to controller to
> update database table.

You could refer the following sample code:

1. Create a ViewModel to display records:

   ```
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int idtip { get; set; }
        public string idemployee { get; set; }
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. In the Controller, add the following actions:

   ```
    //Set the initial data and return to view.
    public  IActionResult Default()
    {
        List<TestViewModel> items = new List<TestViewModel>()
        {
            new TestViewModel(){ id=101, idtip=1001, idemployee="AAA" },
             new TestViewModel(){id=102,idtip=1002, idemployee="BBB" },
              new TestViewModel(){id=103, idtip=1003, idemployee="CCC" },
               new TestViewModel(){ id=104,idtip=1004, idemployee="DDD" },
                new TestViewModel(){id=105, idtip=1005, idemployee="EEE" }
        };

        ViewBag.idemployee = "CCC"; //set the default checked item.
        return View(items);
    }

    public IActionResult AddItems(IEnumerable<TestViewModel> items)
    {
        //insert the items into database.
        return Ok("OK");
    }
   ```
3. Then, in the View page (Default.cshtml), using the following code to display the content:

   Here we can use a select all checkbox, after checking it, will select all items.

   ```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.TestViewModel> 
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Default";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="btnSelectAll" class="btnClick" /> <label for="btnSelectAll">Select All</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.idtip)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.idemployee)
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="pure-checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip">
                        <input type="checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip" data-idemployee="@item.idemployee" class="checktip"
                               checked="@(item.idemployee == ViewBag.idemployee ? true : false)"
                               name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
                        <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idtip)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idemployee)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btnClick">Submit</button>
   ```

   At the end of the Default.cshtml page, using the following script to achieve the select all function and submit the records to the controller.

   ```
    @section Scripts{ 
        <script>
            $(function () {
                //If checked the select all checkbox, select all items. else unchecked.
                $("#btnSelectAll").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $(".checktip").each(function (index, item) {
                            $(item).prop("checked", true);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".checktip").each(function (index, item) {
                            $(item).prop("checked", false);
                        });
                    }
                });

                $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                    var testViewModels = [];
                    //using the class selector to loop through the checkbox list and get all items, if you want to get the checked items, add an if...else statement in the each function.
                    $(".checktip").each(function (index, item) { 
                        var TestViewModel = {}; 
                        TestViewModel.idtip = $(this).attr("idtip");
                        TestViewModel.idemployee = $(this).attr("data-idemployee");
                        TestViewModel.isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
                        testViewModels.push(TestViewModel);
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "/Home/AddItems",  //remember change the controller to your owns. 
                        data: { items: testViewModels },  //the name ("items") should be the same with the parameter's name in the controller.
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data) 
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.log(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    }
   ```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Great, and thank for that, that works perfect for me, In my solution I have a table in database with columns ,idemployee,idtip and when i select all `idtip` for employee can i update that columns with `FormCollection items`? ex. idtip = 4 , idemployee = 2